# powershell send pipe input to pipe

Tags: sorting, powershell, pipe, pipeline

I have a script that accepts piped parameters.
I can't be sure that the user has already piped their input through Sort-Object before piping to my script so I want to send the piped input out for sorting (and other processing) before I begin operating on it in my script.

The script has the following parameters:

```
$script:creds
$script:confObj
function Get-ConfigureServerInput
{
<#
#>

[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "FromPipe")]

Param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="FromUser", Mandatory=$true, Position=0)] [string[]]$ComputerName,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="FromUser", Mandatory=$true, Position=1)] [string[]]$AppName,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="FromUser", Mandatory=$true, Position=2)] [string[]]$key,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="FromUser", Mandatory=$true, Position=3)] [string[]]$setting,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="FromPipe", Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [PSObject]$pobj,

    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="FromFile", Mandatory=$true)] [string]$File,

    [Parameter()] [switch]$force,
    [Parameter()] [switch]$mt,
    [Parameter()] [int]$MaxThreads = 0,
    [Parameter()] [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$Credentials
)

BEGIN
{
    #Runs once regardless of how many items are in the pipe
    If ($Credentials -ne $null) {$script:creds = $Credentials}

    Switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
    {
        "FromPipe" 
        {
            Write-Verbose "Input is from pipe"
            $script:confObj = $($pobj)
            break
        }
        "FromUser"
        {
            Write-Verbose "Input is from user arguments"
            $uObj = New-Object PSObject
            $uObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ComputerName -value $ComputerName
            $uObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name AppName -value $AppName
            $uObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name key -value $key
            $uObj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name setting -value $setting
            $script:confObj = $uObj
            break
        }
        "FromFile"
        {
            Write-Verbose "Input is from file"
            Write-Verbose "Import-CSV -Header 'ComputerName','AppName','key','setting' -path $File "
            $script:confObj = Import-CSV -Header "ComputerName","AppName","key","setting" -path $File 
            break
        }
    }
    $script:confObj
}
```

I think what I need is something in the BEGIN block like:

```
$input = $input | Sort-Object ComputerName,AppName,key,setting -Unique
```

But there doesn't appear to be an $input variable in the BEGIN block. If I put a $input | Get-Member in the BEGIN block I get the error:

```
Get-Member : No object has been specified to the get-member cmdlet.
At E:\Powershell\ConfigureServer\ConfigureServer.psm1:53 char:22
+         $input | Get-Member <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand
```

I can put the Sort-Object line in the PROCESS block, but as expected I get one object at a time and each one is sorted by itself resulting in non-sorted data.

Any recommendations on how I can run my incoming pipe through some filters (e.g.: Sort-Object) before I process it in my script (other than relying on the user to pipe the output of Sort-Object to my script)?

This is how I'm sending an object to my script:

```
Import-CSV -header "ComputerName","AppName","key","setting" duplicates.dat | Get-Member
```

Shown here going to Get-Member to see that I am getting an object.

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name         MemberType   Definition
----         ----------   ----------
Equals       Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode  Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType      Method       type GetType()
ToString     Method       string ToString()
AppName      NoteProperty System.String AppName=garbage
ComputerName NoteProperty System.String ComputerName=google.com
key          NoteProperty System.String key=trash
setting      NoteProperty System.String setting=null
```

Calling it with a -File or with -ComputerName (and the other mandatory args) results in an object that I'm expecting. e.g.:

```
PS E:\Powershell\ConfigureServer> Get-ConfigureServerInput -Verbose -File duplicates.dat
VERBOSE: Input is from file
VERBOSE: Import-CSV -Header 'ComputerName','AppName','key','setting' -path duplicates.dat

ComputerName                  AppName                       key                           setting
------------                  -------                       ---                           -------
google.com                    garbage                       trash                         null
alpha                         nonsense                      nilhilist                     nil
yahoo.com                     aname                         akey                          avalue
alpha                         nonsense                      nilhilist                     nil
yahoo.com                     aname                         akey                          avalue
```

Calling with piped input returns no output.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the parameters you have declared: `$ComputerName`, `$AppName`, `$key`, `$setting`.

You could perhaps reconstruct the something similar to the original objects using `Add-Member`, and then sort those.

Comment: To make this even more generic, what I really want to do is pre-process the entire pipeline in the BEGIN block before working on individual elements (foreach) in the PROCESS block. I want to sort the pipeline and remove duplicates.